# Client asked for Yahoo, Bing and Google analytics

Tags: seo, analytics

I've been tasked with picking up a project where the last developer just quit. One thing said developer was planning to do was add Flurry Analytics (Yahoo) to my client's website.

The site already has Bing and Google analytics. My immediate thought was to remove Bing and tell her how dumb that is (in a nice way) as I've always been happy with ga and having more than one seems redundant.

But I thought I'd ask. Does it ever make sense to have all three of these? Perhaps they help tie into ad campaigns in some way I'm unaware of.

Is it even worthwhile to have more than one, maybe for comparing data?

Answer (score 2):

You should think in a way to solve the problem with minimum overhead.

If you need to analyse the traffic in general then GA should be good enough.

Having said that if you may have a certain requirement which GA can not fulfil then there is nothing wrong considering other available tools.

You also need to realise that the more tool you may have it might slow down the website.

There are some situations where GA might not be good enough. For example tracking IP, so choosing some other tool which can provide this info is absolutely fine.

What i am hinting at is, understand you need.